# AWS refuses the key.pem if permissions on folder are changed

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I'm using a Linux server from AWS and have been encountering the issue of `Server refused our key` and I couldn't login to the server anymore (The key and the login accounts `ec2-user` are correct as I've been connecting for days already).

After some investigation I found out the the issue occurs when I change the permission on the account's folder. In this case, the `/home/ec2-user/`, by default it has --- on group, by running the command `chmod g-rwx /home/ec2-user/` to allow access for the `ec2-user` (I have `nginx` user added to `ec2-user` which needs the access).

Once the above is applied, if I try to connect, I always get the `Server refused our key` message, tried restarting the server, creating new servers, same scenario. I only managed to figure it out by keeping one PuTTY connection open, changing the permissions, trying another session, shows the error, I set the permissions back to what they were, connects successfully.

I'm very newbie still to Linux, so can someone enlighten me if possible on what might be causing this issue or whether it's something on AWS?

Note: I'm referring to connecting with the `.pem` file which was converted properly to the right `.ppk` file, I've been connected for a while and working on the server, so the `credentials` are **not** the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Nothing to do with AWS. This is how `ssh` is supposed to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shot yourself in the foot.

The more specific explanation for what happened is related to the permissions on `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

This is a list of the public ssh keys whose matching private key can be used to log in as you.

Make this file writable by anyone other than yourself, and the implications are obvious: anyone who can write to this file can add an arbitrary public key to the list, thereby allowing them to log in as you.

The secure shell daemon, `sshd` sees this misconfiguration, and calls foul -- if the file of authorized keys is compromised by being writable by anyone other than you, then its contents are inherently unsafe, and it therefore is ignored... and since that's the mechanism by which your key was trusted to allow you to log in... you no longer can.

This is by design, standard *nix behavior, and unrelated to AWS.

Recursively changing permissions is unwise unless you absolutely know what you're doing.

Comment: Clear and to the point, thanks mate, I ended up moving everything to `/var/www` as suggested in the other post, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Avoid change permissions to the ec2-user.
Homedir permissions require that you clear understand what you are doing before change it.

If you require a `nginx` user to use it own space, try to create at `/opt` or where it has by default `/var/www`.

Comment: I ended up doing this which solved all the issues, however, I'm selecting the other answer as accepted since it answers the asked question, thanks.